# Why isn't 'return' breaking my loop?

Tags: javascript

Here is the test I am trying to pass:

```
describe("occur", function() {
  var getVal = function(i) { return i; };
  var even = function(num) { return num % 2 === 0; };

  it("should handle an empty set", function() {
    expect(occur([], getVal) ).toEqual(true);
  });

  it("should handle a set that contains only true values", function() {
    expect(occur([true, true, false], getVal)).toEqual(false);
  });

  it("should handle a set that contains one false value", function() {
    expect(occur([true, true, true], getVal)).toEqual(true);
  });

  it("should handle a set that contains even numbers", function() {
    expect(occur([0, 8, 32], even)).toEqual(true);
  });

  it("should handle a set that contains an odd number", function() {
    expect(occur([0, 13, 68], even)).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

Here is my code:

```
var forEach = function(array, action){
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
    action(array[i]);
  }
};

var occur = function(array, blah){
  forEach(array, function(el){
    if(!blah(el)){
      return false;
    }
  });
    return true;  
};
```

What I believe I am doing in my occur function:

1. Taking parameters(an array and a function
2. Iterating over the array (in the forEach)
3. If blah(el) isn't true, return false (shouldn't this break the loop and return false whenever there the function passed in evaluates to false?
4. return true if there aren't any false values
5. **I do not have a case currently implemented for an empty array.

Am I missing a trick with how return works? I provided a repl.it session of it below (link). I included a console.log inside my if statement and it does log 'false' when a value is false but the return value still doesn't output or break the loop.

http://repl.it/NjH/1

Comment: return *only ever* returns from the *nearest enclosing function*. That is, the callback to `forEach` in the above code. (The `forEach` function doesn't return anything useful, I would create an `any/some` or a `filter` - both of which exist in ES5/5.1 - instead and use the return value.)

Comment: I think one of my issues with my understanding is not fully wrapping my head around 'callback' functions.  I'm not too sure what you mean by 'nearest enclosing function'. How is 'nearest' determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue is that `return` *always* exits the *nearest enclosing function* - and no other.

```
var occur = function(array, blah){ // <-- "outer" function
  forEach(array, function(el){ // <-- callback to forEach / "enclosing" function
    if(!blah(el)){
      // This returns from the callback/enclosing function; it has no
      // bearing on the outer function.
      return false;
    }
  });
  return true;  
};
```

Barring changing approaches, this problem can be solved with using a variable.

```
var occur = function(array, blah){
  var ret = true;
  forEach(array, function(el){
    if(!blah(el)){
      // Set the closed-over variable to false, so that when the return
      // in the outer function is reached the correct value will be returned.
      // (forEach will still iterate over every remaining item)
      ret = false;
    }
  });
  return ret;  
};
```

Now, my recommendation is to use something like [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (which is in ES5.1 and supported in IE9+ and every modern browser of note).

```
var occur = function(array, blah){
  var any = array.some(function(el){
    if(!blah(el)){
      return true;
    }
  });
  return !any;
};
```

But really, changing the conditions (negations inside/outside and `some` to `every`):

```
var occur = function(array, blah){
  return array.every(function(el){
    return blah(el);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` does not return a value in Javascript-- when you return `false`, you're simply returning `false` from `forEach`'s callback. The value is ignored.

Instead, you could try `Array.every()` if you're using a compatible implementation like Node/Webkit/something that supports ECMAScript 5.

Otherwise, set a semaphore variable outside the `forEach`, and set it to false if `blah(el)` returns false. Then check the value of the variable after the `forEach` is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't missing a trick about `return`, you're missing one about `.forEach`.

For each basically looks like this:

```
function forEach (action) {
    var arr = this,
        i = 0, l = arr.length;

    for (; i < l; i += 1) {
        action(arr[i], i, arr);
    }
}
```

There's more to it than just that, but really, that's what it's doing.

So if `action()` has a `return` statement in it (and even if it doesn't, it just returns `undefined`, it doesn't matter to the loop at all.

It says "forEach" and what it will get you is one pass through every single item in the array (that exists at the time the function is called).

Comment: @user2864740 It doesn't fix the problem with return. It highlights the problem with return, answering the "am I missing a trick with how return works", as it is verbatim a naive implementation of `.forEach`, to show, in detail, what the problem is, to learn to fish, rather than to catch one.  The longer answer, in addendum to this, can come later.

Comment: @user2864740 Bah. You are correct -- my failure was in neglecting to notice that it wasn't the native `Array.prototype. forEach`, and as such, I overlooked the nature of the misunderstanding. Using `[ ].forEach` without understanding the loop/callback relationship is not the issue. My apologies; I will update this answer, during my next mental break.